Настройка ODBC для MS SQL Server Express
Существует база данных на основе MS SQL Server Express.
Данную базу необходимо мигрировать на MySQL. Я узнал о способе через ODBC, но не удается его настроить для моего сервера.
Когда я пытаюсь добавить системный DSN в Администраторе источника данных ODBC через SQL Server-драйвер, введя имя сервера - (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB, я получаю ошибку "SQL Server не существует, или доступ запрещён":

Может я не угадал с драйвером или для локального сервера SQL Server Express нельзя настраивать ODBC?
